# How to use ICU BreakIterator with a Unicode text file in C++

Tags: c++, unicode, icu

I am having trouble using the ICU BreakIterator on a whole UTF-8 Khmer (Cambodian) text file in order to break words for line-breaks (Khmer has no spaces between words like Thai).

I used a sample given to me, and modified it to read a text file line by line, but the problem is if the line only has one word on it, the BreakIterator does not work well, as we have it configured to try to find at least 3 words in a row (this is necessary for Khmer, and without it, the BreakIterator is not as accurate).

Can someone help me understand how to overcome this problem?  I thought it easiest way would be to read a whole text file into a buffer, but I can't seem to get it work work properly.

Here is the whole code I currently have that breaks words from a text file line by line:

```
/*
Written by George Rhoten, and SBBIC to test how word segmentation works.
Code inspired by the break ICU sample.

Here is an example to run this code in Ubuntu.

./a.out input.txt output.txt

Encode input.txt as UTF-8.
The output text is UTF-8.
*/

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unicode/brkiter.h>
#include <unicode/ucnv.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ZW_SPACE "\xE2\x80\x8B"

void printUnicodeString(const UnicodeString &s) {
    int32_t len = s.length() * U8_MAX_LENGTH + 1;
    char *charBuf = new char[len];
    len = s.extract(0, s.length(), charBuf, len, NULL);
    charBuf[len] = 0;
    printf("%s", charBuf);
    delete charBuf;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {   


    //Please provide an input file name as well as an output file name (ex. ./a.out input.txt output.txt)

    //Cannot find the input file you specified ("$input"). Please provide an input file name as well as an output file name (ex. ./a.out input.txt output.txt)

    //Cannot write to output file.  Please check folder permissions.

    std::ifstream input(argv[1]);
    //std::ifstream input("read.txt");
    std::string line;
    std::ofstream o(argv[2]);    
    //std::ofstream o("output.txt");


    //If input file cannot be found ERROR
    if (!input) {
        std::cout<<"Cannot find the input file you specified ("<<argv[1]<<").\nPlease provide an input file name as well as an output file name\n(example: ./a.out input.txt output.txt)"<<std::endl;
        goto stop;  
    }
    //If output file cannot be created ERROR
    if (!o) {
        std::cout<<"Cannot write to output file ("<<argv[2]<<").\nPlease check folder permissions."<<std::endl;
        goto stop;  

    }
    //If no input file is given on command line ERROR
    if(argv[1]==0) {
        std::cout<<"Please provide an input file name as well as an output file name\n(example: ./a.out input.txt output.txt)"<<std::endl;
        goto stop;
    }
    //If no output file is given on command line ERROR
    if(argv[2]==0) {
        std::cout<<"Please provide output file name as well as an input file name\n(example: ./a.out input.txt output.txt)"<<std::endl;
        goto stop;
    }


    while(std::getline(input,line)) {


//Convert standard string to icu UnicodeString

    UnicodeString Nathan = UnicodeString::fromUTF8(StringPiece(line.c_str()));


/* Creating and using text boundaries */
    ucnv_setDefaultName("UTF-8");
    UnicodeString stringToExamine(Nathan);
    if (argc > 1) {
        // Override the default charset.
        stringToExamine = UnicodeString(Nathan);
        if (stringToExamine.charAt(0) == 0xFEFF) {
            // Remove the BOM
            stringToExamine = UnicodeString(stringToExamine, 1);
        }
    }
    //printUnicodeString(stringToExamine);
    //puts("");

    //print each sentence in forward and reverse order
    UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    BreakIterator* boundary = BreakIterator::createLineInstance(NULL, status);
    if (U_FAILURE(status)) {
        printf("Failed to create sentence break iterator. status = %s", 
            u_errorName(status));
        exit(1);
    }

    //print each word in order
    boundary->setText(stringToExamine);
    int32_t start = boundary->first();
    int32_t end = boundary->next();
    while (end != BreakIterator::DONE) {
        if (start != 0) {
            printf(ZW_SPACE);

         //output ZWSpace to output file(output.txt)
            o << ZW_SPACE;


            //filestr<<ZW_SPACE;
            //filestr.close();



        }
        //Set variable NathanOut to current word and print to console
        UnicodeString NathanOut = UnicodeString(stringToExamine, start, end-start);
        printUnicodeString(NathanOut);



        //Convert UnicodeString to normal string
            std::string cs;
            NathanOut.toUTF8String(cs);
     //Output the string to file(output.txt)
            o << cs;


            //print output to console
            printUnicodeString(NathanOut);


        start = end;
        end = boundary->next();
    }

    delete boundary;



    }//end of while

    stop:
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: would any one helps with this problem please

Comment: were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @khmerdeveloper what have you figure it out? Can you answer to your question? I want to experience it as well.

Comment: I suspect that you need to supply the locale in the constructor, for it to work.